# Apache Flink delay processing of certain events

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-cep

I have a requirement to delay processing of some of the events.

eg. I have three events (published on Kafka):

- A (id: 1, retryAt: now)
- B (id: 2, retryAt: 10 minutes later)
- C (id: 3, retryAt: now)

I need to process record A and C immediately while record B needs to be processed Ten minutes later.
Is this something feasible to achieve in Apache Flink?

So far whatever I have researched, it seems, "Triggers" is something which might help to achieve it in Flink but have not been able to implement it correctly yet.

I looked through Kafka documentation too, but it doesn't look feasible there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Triggers are for windows, but windowing doesn't seem appropriate for your use case.

A better solution would be to use Timers with a `KeyedProcessFunction`. Depending on whether you want to wait for 10 minutes of processing time, or 10 minutes of event time, you'll choose processing time timers or event time timers.

You'll also need to use Flink state to store the events that need to be processed later.

You'll find the documentation for process functions [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/operators/process_function/). There are some additional examples in the Flink training, [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/learn-flink/event_driven/) and [here](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/tree/master/long-ride-alerts).

FWIW, Flink's Stateful Functions API might be a better fit for what you're doing, in which case you would use [delayed messages](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-statefun-docs-stable/docs/sdk/java/#sending-delayed-messages).

Comment: Thanks David. It was useful info. "Flink state to store the events to be processed later": For this, do I need to use RocksDB or any external DB. Because, In-Memory storage would lose the message when Flink node goes down.

Comment: Flink relies on checkpointing for fault tolerance. Working state is managed by state backends, and is either stored in-memory if you choose the `HashMapStateBackend`, or on the local disk if you choose the `EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend`.

Comment: Hi David, could you provide your opinion on another Flink question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68725502/flink-with-atomic-sink-function